# Erro na linha mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysqli

Isto é um buscador de informações de universidades, meu TCC.
Este é o erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$mysqlli = new mysqli($servidor,$user,$senha,$banco);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());
else
echo "sucesso";

//@mysql_select_db("faculdadesbd",$mysqlli);
```

?>


Unigle

    body{
        font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        color:#333;
        font-size:12px;
    }

---

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['botao'])){
        $busca = $_POST['busca'];

        $busca_dividida = explode(' ',$busca);
        $quant = count($busca_dividida);

        for($i=0;$i<$quant;$i++){
            $pesquisa = $busca_dividida[$i];

            $sql = ("SELECT * FROM busca WHERE nome_fac LIKE '%$.pesquisa.%'");
            $query = $mysqlli->query($sql);
            while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $nome_fac = $linha['Nome'];
                $data_vest = $linha['Data Vestibular'];
                $data_taxa = $linha['Data Taxa'];
                $nota_corte = $linha['Nota de corte'];
                $nota_enem = $linha['Nota ENEM'];

                echo"
                    <div class='resultado'>
                        <h2>".$nome_fac."</h2>
                        <p>".$data_vest."</p>
                        <p>".$data_taxa."</p>
                        <p>".$nota_corte."</p>
                        <p>".$nota_enem."</p>
                    </div>
                    ";
        }
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ajude-nos a te ajudar. O que diz o erro?

Comment: Na outra [perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41466/91) estava `mysql_fetch_array($sql)` fique atento para usar somente um driver de conexão com o banco de preferência o mysql**i**. Veja como o site funciona na [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), [como perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e não esqueça de fazer um debug ;)

Comment: Eu confundi na hora de colar o código só.

Comment: Coloque: ´$query->fetch_assoc()` no lugar de `mysql_fetch_array($sql)`

Comment: Ocorreram os seguintes erros ao substituir mysql_fetch_array($sql) por ´$query->fetch_assoc()`: http://i.imgur.com/QVBLwv6.png?1

Comment: No código da pergunta não tem nenhuma variável chamada consulta. Verifique os nomes das variáveis, se precisar edite a pergunte e coloque o código correto.

Comment: A variável consulta é a $query. Me desculpe, postei o erro em português, aqui está ele em inglês se ajuda em algo: http://i.imgur.com/GLrStAL.png

Comment: `query()` retorna false quando a consulta tem algum erro, exiba assim o erro do banco: `$query = $mysqlii->query($sql); if(!$query){ echo $mysqlii->error;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser apenas um erro de digitação, seu objeto de conexão é `$mysqlli` e na hora de chamar o método `query()` você chama uma variável que não existe `$mysqli`. Para corrigir troque a chamada de:

```
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

por:

```
$query = $mysqlli->query($sql);
```

Quando uma tela em branco é exibida, isso significa duas coisas aconteceu um erro e a exibição dos erros foi ocultada(geralmente por motivos de segurança). Nesse caso é possível os erros sobrescrevendo essa configuração, as linhas a seguir devem estar no o início do seu arquivo.

```
 <?php
 ini_set('display_errors', true);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

 echo '...';
```

A linha abaixo pode ser removida, e evite usar `@` pois ela oculta os erros, o que dificulta mais a resolução do bug.

```
@mysql_select_db("faculdadesbd",$mysqlli);
```